# Abstract Factory Method pattern not working with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have problem with Abstract Factory pattern implementation on Spring. I am using Spring 3 MVC and Hibernate 3, which works fine if I don't use Abstract Factory Method pattern.
I am not sure what I have to add to the Controller to have access the Factory Class (CategoryFactory).

Is there anything missing in the Controller or bean initiating ?

```
class SectionsController extends MultiActionController {
    /* Do I have to initiate the CategoryFactory here? */

    public ModelAndView secList() throws Exception {
        CategoryFactory.CategoryType type = CategoryFactory.CategoryType.valueOf("view");
        modelMap.addAttribute("sectionList", CategoryFactory.findCategory(type).list(id));
        return new ModelAndView("Form", modelMap);
    }
}
```

Abstract Factory

```
public abstract class Category {
    public abstract List list(int departId);
}

public class CategoryFactory {
    public enum CategoryType { firstclass, secondClass, ... }
    public static Category findCategory(CategoryType categoryType) {
        // Create type specific Category implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try and put *some* effort into formatting your question. It's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

It shoud be:
class SectionsController extends MultiActionController {

```
  private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```

public ModelAndView secList() throws Exception {
   CategoryFactory.CategoryType type=CategoryFactory.CategoryType.valueOf("view");
     modelMap.addAttribute("sectionList",CategoryFactory.findCategory(type).list(hibernateTemplate,id);
      return new ModelAndView("Form", modelMap);
     }
 }